# What is the equivalent of batch for windows on android?

Tags: android

I want to make a simple script that starts recording and stops recording and sends the record as an E-mail attachment. Is that possible on Android? If not what language should I choose to create some alternative (for example an app)?

If you downvote follow, or at least tell me what's wrong in the comments.

 Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check it. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/36359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want run shell comand in Android app you can use this code:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( " your comand here " );
```

Anyway there is no something like batch scripts. There is only applications.